# How do I convert timestamp to string in Liquid?

Tags: ruby, liquid, jekyll

I'm migrating my site from Drupal to Jekyll. In the YAML Front Matter of each post, I have the timestamp it was created.

`{{ page.created }} => 1287199856`

In Liquid, how do I convert that to:

`2010-10-15 23:30:56 -0400`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure, but hope this works

```
Page Created {{ page.created | date: "%F %H:%M:%S %z" }}
```

Refer [this site](http://wiki.shopify.com/UsingLiquid)

Comment: That would work if `page.created` were a Ruby Time object, but in my case, it's just a Fixnum. How do I get the Time object from a Fixnum in Liquid. I know in Ruby, it's `Time.at(1287199856)`.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible. I'll mark your answer as correct because I think it's the closest to correct we can get. I think I'll just go with HAML instead.